# How do I match the regular expression pattern within the content of a file without looping through each line in the file?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Im searching for a pattern within a file.  This pattern is not limited to a single line.  It spreads over more than one line, i.e. more than one line group together to contain this pattern. Hence, it's not possible to loop through line-by-line in the file and check whether the pattern exists or not. The pattern is given below:

`/public.+\s+(\w+)\([^\)]*\)\s*.+?return\s*\w+?\.GetQuestion\s*\(/g`

Can anyone please tell the C# coding how to match the pattern with in the file ?

Comment: Holy Crap!!!  11 questions and not one of them was worth an acceptance?!!  You gotta give to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you need to read the whole file (using `ReadToEnd`, as suggested by RandomNoob) but then also specify [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) to put it into [Singleline mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline):

> The RegexOptions.Singleline option, or the s inline option, causes the regular expression engine to treat the input string as if it consists of a single line. It does this by changing the behavior of the period (.) language element so that it matches every character, instead of matching every character except for the newline character \n or \u000A.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(
    @"public.+\s+(\w+)\([^\)]*\)\s*.+?return\s*\w+?\.GetQuestion\s*\(",
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: I'm going to print this page and put it in my cube because Jon Skeet typed my name

Answer (score 1):

Use StreamReader [ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) and match against it?